# Regular expression circular matching

Tags: regex

Using regular expressions (in any language) is there a way to match a pattern that wraps around from the end to the beginning of a string? For example, if i want the match the pattern:

"street"

against the string:

m = "et stre"

it would match m[3:] + m[:2]

Comment: Are you asking is there a way to get it to match any part of your match string.  even if it doesn't math the entire querry?

Comment: Why not concatenating the string with itself and doing a normal match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that directly in the regexp. What you can do is some arithmetic. Append the string to itself:

```
m = "et stre"
n = m + m //n = "et street stre"
```

If there is an odd number of matches in `n` (in this case, 1), the match was 'circular'. If not, there were no circular matches, and the number of matches in `n` is the double of the number of matches in `m`.

Comment: OK. I wasn't sure if there was some built-in way to do that. Some of the strings i have to deal with are rather large.

Comment: But that will fail if you need to loop more than once, e.g. I would assume that the regexp "aaaaa" should be circularly matched in the string "aa"...